# Integrate multivariate python function with one positional argument

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

suppose I define a function of an unpackable array (e.g. list)

```
def f(params):
    a,b,c = params
    return a+b**2+c**2
```

is there a way to integrate over only the first parameter? I tried

```
import scipy.integrate.quad as quad

def integrate(b,c):
    return quad(f,0,1,args=(b,c))
```

but it returns an error because the function `f` only takes one positional argument. I guess I have to unpack it in the integration step, but unsure how.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try making `f`’s signature `*params` instead of `params`? That will still throw an exception for too many or too few parameters to unpack

Comment: The problem I have with that is if I try now f([0,1,2]), I get an error, and I wanted to put list/array input

Comment: Try `f(*[0,1,2])`

Comment: nice thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two use cases for using this function you can do something like the following:

```
def f(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        a,b,c = args[0]
    else:
        a, b,c  = args
    return a+b**2+c**2
```

This assumes that if you pass one argument to the function in can be unpacked and if you pass more than one you pass `a, b, c` directly.

In a more generic setting, you can define different behavior of a function depending on the input type using `functools.singledispatch`. In this case this would look as follows:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def f(arg1, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    a, b, c = arg1
    return a+b**2+c**2

@f.register(int)
@f.register(float)
def _(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return arg1+arg2**2+arg3**2
```

The advantage of this would be that you can extend it for different input types if that is needed.